# Different size images in website depending on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, image, screen-resolution, src

I have a website with some images, and for this the page loading can be slow on mobile devices that have only mobile internet connection.
So, my question is: assign different images, smaller or bigger depending on device, when page is loaded  could be a solution?

Example
Initially my img in the dom could be:

```
<img src="" id="img1" alt="img1" />
```

And then, adding a script in head:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
               loadImg();
            })
```

The loadImg function can be like:

```
if((window.screen.availHeight < 1234)&&(window.screen.availWidth < 1234))
document.getElementById("img1").src = "small";
else
document.getElementById("img1").src = "big";
```

Comment: You should have a look at [CSS 3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), e.g. @media screen and (max-width: 1234px) { … then small bg img ... }

Comment: @StuartLC: thank you for the answer, but, using media queries (for what I know) I can't change source and with it I can resize images after is loaded so the "weight" is that of original image..

Answer (score 0):

Try this js library https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

I don't know how this affects the SEO, though.